# Extract an integer from beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How do i extract "3200:-" from this?

`<p class="list_price font-large" itemprop="price">3 200:-</p>`

```
price = soup.find_all("p", {"class": "list_price font-large"}, {"itemprop": "price"})[0]

def get_price():
    for integer in price:
        return(integer)
print(get_price())
```

and it prints out 3200 for me, but how can I do this more effectively?

Comment: Having a return in a for loop doesn't seem correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That loop isn't necessary, and if you only want the first item, don't use `find_all`

```
price = soup.find("p", {"class": "list_price font-large"}, {"itemprop": "price"}).text
```

Note, you're not getting an integer. `3 200:-` is a string.

If you want an integer, you'll need to separately filter out all non numeric values from the string, then cast using `int()`

Answer (score 0):

`3 200:-` is the text of the node. You can use `.text` attribute to access it:

```
s = '<p class="list_price font-large" itemprop="price">3 200:-</p>'
​
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
price = soup.find_all("p", {"class": "list_price font-large"}, {"itemprop": "price"})
​
for node in price:
    print(node.text)
# 3 200:-
```

Then you can remove the white spaces in the way you want to:

```
for node in price:
    print(node.text.replace(' ', ''))

# 3200:-
```

Or if you just want the number, you can use `re` module to remove all non digits from the string:

```
import re
for node in price:
    print(re.sub(r'\D', '', node.text))
# 3200
```

Answer (score 0):

```
price= soup.find("p", {"class": "list_price font-large"}, {"itemprop": "price"}).text
# price => '3 200:-'
price = price.replace(' ','')
# price => '3200:-'
import re
price = int(re.search('[0-9]+',price).group(0))
# price =>3200
```